Using conditional 'if' inside 'extend' block in Leaf 4.4.0
I'm trying to extend a template by conditionally checking for a field in the context object. In this example I want staff.leaf to conditionally pass data to the #import("body") of master.leaf:
staff.leaf
#extend("master"):

#export("title"):Staff#endexport
#export("h1"): Hello there! #endexport

#if(name):
#export("body"):#(name) is the name#endexport
#else:
#export("body"):No name!#endexport
#endif

#endextend

master.leaf
<html>
    <head>
        <title>#import("title")</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>#import("h1")</h1>
        #import("body")
        #extend("footer")
    </body>
</html>

However, when I visit the route that renders staff.leaf Leaf produces the error:
{"reason":"unexpected token in extend body: conditional:\n  if(variable(name)):\n    raw(\"\\n\")\n    export(\"body\"):\n      expression[variable(name)]\n      raw(\" is the name\")\n    raw(\"\\n\")\n  else:\n    raw(\"\\n\")\n    export(\"body\"):\n      raw(\"No name!\")\n    raw(\"\\n\").. use raw space and `export` only","error":true}

Is this approach not supported in Leaf? If not, what is the proper way to accomplish this?
